# Responsive bootstrap not working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My site is rainychat.com.

I made it responsive with bootstrap for mobile, and when i try it on my pc by making my browser smaller to imitate that it looks fine:

[image: On browser]

However when i try it on my phone it doesnt work properly:

[image: On mobile]

Why is this happening? The website is live on rainychat.com

Comment: Have you tried adding the [viewport meta tag](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) ?

Comment: clear your mobile browser cache and history. many times its happen to me after clear cache only solved for me. just try this

Comment: Already have my viewport tag :
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">. And already erased cache.. its not that..

Comment: Have you checked DevTools because you have multiple **head** and **html** tags: one set inside the **frame** and another outside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use this meta tags?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Already had the viewport meta tag, added the X-UA-Compatible one and tried again, but nothing. I think it only affects internet explorer compatibility anyway.

Comment: when i watch yesterday there aren't meta tags anyway now the site on my phone it's working